# Buildling boxplots incrementally from large datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ram

Let s say i have 4 files saved on my computer as .npz files : W,X,Y and Z.
Let s assume that my computer can not endure to load at the same time more than one of them in term of RAM consumption.

How can I  be able to run this command ? :

```
 matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot([W],[X],[Y],[Z])
```

In other terms, how can I load W, plot W, delete W then load Y, plot Y, delete Y, ... and have the 4 of them on the same figure ? ( and not a subplot )

Thank you !

Comment: [Is this answer useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16368570/2327328)

Comment: This is an interesting comment. I am going to try it ASAP. Thank you

Comment: I am affraid it does nto work for my case ... It doesn ot solve the RAM management issue, it is above what I can take

Comment: You might want to consider to change the title to something more descriptive... Maybe: "Buildling boxplots incrementally from large datasets"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`matplotlib.axes.boxplot`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2943) function actually calls two functions under the hood. One to compute the necessary statistics ([`cbook.boxplot_stats`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py#L1937)) and one to actually draw the plot ([`matplotlib.axes.bxp`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3180)). You can exploit this structure, by calling the first for each dataset (by loading one at a time) and then feed the results to the plotting function.

In this example below we have 3 datasets and iterate over them to collect the output of `cbook.boxplot_stats` (which needs only very little memory). After that call to `ax.bxp` creates the graph. (In your application you would iteratively load a file, use `boxplot_stats` and delete the data)

```
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.random.rand(10,10)
y = np.random.rand(10,10)
z = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

bxpstats = list()
for dataset, label in zip([x, y, z], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']):
    bxpstats.extend(cbook.boxplot_stats(np.ravel(dataset), labels=[label]))
ax.bxp(bxpstats)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow ! It seems that what you propose is exactly what I was looking for. I am going to try it asap and I ll let you know ! Thank you !

Comment: I do not find boxplot_stats in cbook output ... I guess I do not have the right version of it, I need to look further in it. But I understood what you proposed to me , and it seems just fine

Comment: I believe that the boxplot function was heavily refactored in v1.4 of matplotlib. So if you use an older version, this solution will not work. To check your version of matplotlib you can run `import matplotlib; print matplotlib.__version__`. If it is older than 1.4, I would suggest to update it

Comment: Hi. Yes I checked that, I run a 1.3.1 version. It is not my computer, but somebody's at work, which I do not own the sudo rights to update packages ... I need to wait until he can do that for me . But still thanks !

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass a random sample of your data to the plotting function.

Or, because the boxplot contains only aggregate data, so you should consider calculating those aggregate values separately, and then applying them to the boxplot visualization.

Using the full option list from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot), you may be able to construct boxplots by passing aggregate data:

```
boxplot(self, x, notch=False, sym='b+', vert=True, whis=1.5,
    positions=None, widths=None, patch_artist=False,
    bootstrap=None, usermedians=None, conf_intervals=None,
    meanline=False, showmeans=False, showcaps=True,
    showbox=True, showfliers=True, boxprops=None, labels=None,
    flierprops=None, medianprops=None, meanprops=None,
    capprops=None, whiskerprops=None, manage_xticks=True):
```

See for example usermedians:

> usermedians : array-like or None (default)
>
> An array or sequence whose first dimension (or length) is compatible with x. This overrides the medians computed by matplotlib for each element of usermedians that is not None. When an element of usermedians == None, the median will be computed by matplotlib as normal.

Comment: Hi ! So if I understand correctly, you mean that I should load W, create this agregate, delete W, load X,  ... and then use boxplot to with those agregates  ?

If I translate for instance what you mean by "agregated data", you mean not having anymore a square defined by all the points contained in it, but only by his "skeleton" ? the lines instead of the filling part ?

If so, I have no clue how to do that properly, especially with the huge amount of Data I have ( each W,X ... is 150 Go of 512*512*256*512* Arrays that I turn into reshape(-1) for boxplot

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few approaches to do this.

The first one is the most applicable to this use case, but I'm adding three more for related situations.

### 1. Python (matplotlib + numpy numeric arrays)

If you want to stick with Python, you can follow [hitzg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904940/709975)'s answer. But there are a few critical details to take into consideration. Once you generate the first boxplot, you don't need that data anymore, so ensure you free up that memory. Adapting the other answer, the code looks like this:

```py
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.random.rand(10,10)
y = np.random.rand(10,10)
z = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

bxpstats = list()
for dataset, label in zip([x, y, z], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']):
    bxpstats.extend(cbook.boxplot_stats(np.ravel(dataset), labels=[label]))
    # free up the memory
    del dataset

ax.bxp(bxpstats)
plt.show()
```

If you are using numeric numpy arrays, using `del` will release the memory. However, **this won't work if using numpy objects or pandas data frames** ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100971/how-do-i-release-memory-used-by-a-pandas-dataframe/39377643#39377643)), see next options for alternatives.

### 2. Python (matplotlib + pandas data frames)

If you're using pandas data frames. Then using `del data_frame`, won't release the memory. However, you can compute the boxplot statistics and store them (e.g. in a JSON file) and then kill the process, to ensure the memory is released. You can compute the statistics with [`matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b5ac96a8980fdb9e59c9fb649e0714d776e26701/lib/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py#L1103), store in JSON, load the JSON files in a new process, and use [`bxp`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ddc260ce5a53958839c244c0ef0565160aeec174/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3915) to plot. Something like this:

```bash
python boxplot-stats.py --path some_data.csv
python boxplot-stats.py --path more_data.csv

python plot.py --path some_data.csv --path more_data.csv
```

(of course, you'd need to write the command-line interface to make it work)

### 3. Python (JupySQL) - easiest option if data is in CSV or parquet format

If your data is in `.csv`, or `.parquet` format (or you can convert it), you can use [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql); which has a plotting module that leverages SQL engines to efficiently compute statistics for plotting boxplots and histograms ([example here](https://jupysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duckdb.html#plotting-large-datasets), and [here](https://jupysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html)). Under the hood, it can use [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) to compute the statistics, and then passes them to matplotlib for plotting (without having to load all your data into memory!).

Code looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sql import plot

conn = create_engine('duckdb:///')

plot.boxplot('path/to/data.parquet', 'column_to_plot', conn)
```

Note that you need these packages:

```
pip install jupysql duckdb duckdb-engine pyarrow
```

### 4. DuckDB + Python

Finally, you can use DuckDB directly, this will give you more flexibility, but you'll have to implement quite a few things. For a basic boxplot, all you need are quantiles, which you can quickly compute from DuckDB; here's a template you can use (just substitute the `{{placeholders}}`):

```sql
SELECT
percentile_disc(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "{{column}}") AS q1,
percentile_disc(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "{{column}}") AS med,
percentile_disc(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "{{column}}") AS q3,
AVG("{{column}}") AS mean,
COUNT(*) AS N
FROM "{{path/to/data.parquet}}"
```

To create a complete boxplot, you need a few more statistics. To know exactly which ones and how to compute them, you can use matplotlib's [`boxplot_stats`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b5ac96a8980fdb9e59c9fb649e0714d776e26701/lib/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py#L1103) as reference, then compute the aggregations with DuckDB and the rest in Python, then pass that to matplotlib's [`bxp`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ddc260ce5a53958839c244c0ef0565160aeec174/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3915) function. This is actually how [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql) works, you can use the [implementation](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql/blob/db038ab242bc79d52e8facfd14526d0fe48dda6d/src/sql/plot.py#L180) as reference.